# Location using Dialogflow and Location Sharing

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have a Google Actions sharing location permissions on the Welcome Intent. That's great for Google Assistant but how can I branch the conversation from the start so I can have a Intent for different platforms that of course cannot access the GPS such as Phone Gateway, Telegram and Text?

Comment: Are you asking how you can get location on these other platforms, or how to know if you can't get the location and how to handle it?

Comment: Being an idiot. Of course there are different Platform Welcomes I can use in the Events. Not jus the Dialogflow one . I just use those instead. Sorry to have wasted your time.

Comment: Not a waste at all! I would suggest you document and post your discovery as an answer (StackOverflow allows, and encourages, you to answer your own questions) so other people will similar problems can learn from it.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted different welcomes from different platforms such as Google Assistant or Telegram for example. Then go into Events in Welcome and you can add Welcomes from those platforms instead.